# WiX will not uninstall due to conditions in CustomAction

Tags: wix, installation, uninstallation, custom-action

I have an MSI that uses two CustomActions.  The first adds some stuff to the registry.  It runs every time *except* during uninstall.  The second removes a key from the registry to be run *only* during uninstall.

Both CustomActions work fine, only now the MSI won't uninstall.

By "it won't uninstall" I mean neither the file that is installed is deleted nor is the MSI removed from *Programs and Features* when uninstall is run.  The only thing is *does* do during uninstallation is the Custom Action that removes stuff from the registry.

Note that the problem happens on a fresh Virtual Machine, so it's not like there are old versions with different GUIDs hanging around.

Also I don't think that there's a problem with the Features, as there's only one feature -- a textfile installation (it's a toy installation -- until I get this right it's not going in the real installer).

Here is the `<InstallExecutiveSequence>` code from both Custom Actions.  The one where I put stuff into the registry, to be done every time **except** uninstall:

```
      <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="CustomAction_CreateKey"
                  After="InstallInitialize">
          </Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And here is the same XML from where I delete from the registry, to be done **only** during uninstallation:

```
      <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="CustomAction_DeleteKey"
                  After="InstallInitialize">
              (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")
          </Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The uninstall logs aren't that helpful (at least, to me).  There's this:

> MSI (s) (BC:6C) [15:27:15:733]: Note: 1: 1725
>
> MSI (s) (BC:6C) [15:27:15:733]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
>
> MSI (s) (BC:6C) [15:27:15:733]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT
>   `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1725
>
> MSI (s) (BC:6C) [15:27:15:733]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
>
> MSI (s) (BC:6C) [15:27:15:733]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT
>   `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709
>
> MSI (s) (BC:6C) [15:27:15:733]: Product: CustomActionDeleteKeySetup --
>   Removal failed.

And this:

> Calling custom action DeleteKey!DeleteKey.CustomActions.DeleteTheKey
>
> Exception thrown by custom action:
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException: Cannot
>   access session details from a non-immediate custom action
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.ValidateSessionAccess()
>
> at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.set_Item(String
>   property, String value)
>
> at DeleteKey.CustomActions.DeleteTheKey(Session session)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I'm not really sure what to look for in the log files.

To sum up:  Custom Actions won't let me uninstall.  I'm pulling my hair out.

***EDIT***

I managed to get it working, but I don't know why.  It has something to do with the conditions.
The conditions were this:  when uninstalling *and only* uninstalling, I wanted to remove the key.  So -- as shown above -- here's the `<InstallExecuteSequence>` code:

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomAction_DeleteKey"
              After="InstallInitialize">
          (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")
      </Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And then I wanted to create the key when doing everything *except* installing.  Before, I didn't have any conditions in the `<InstallExecuteSequence>` bit, but when I change it to this, it seems to work (that is, the custom actions work and it uninstalls):

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomAction_CreateKey"
              After="InstallInitialize">
          (NOT installed) OR (CHANGE) OR (REPAIR)
      </Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The question is:  why does it work?  Is it because earlier I was trying to run both Custom Actions during uninstallation?

Comment: You're using `session["PROPERTY"]` in a deferred custom action which is not allowed. Looks like you're specifically trying to set a property value in a deferred custom action `session["PROPERTY"] = "Value";`

Comment: @Brian I realize the logs make it look like I do that, but I really don't.  There's a way to pass a property into C# code during a deferred action, and  I do that.  The C# code looks something like this (I'm encrypting and setting a registry value, so I use the "SetValue()" function that takes the key, name, and value as args):  `Registry.SetValue("Software\\yadda\\yadda", "name", Encrypt(session.CustomActionData["PROPERTY"]));`  That format works for deferred if you use the `SetProperty' element along with the rest of the CustomAction XML.  With that said, I managed to get it to work but why?